# how to get same Background drawable with different button android

Tags: android, xml, background, drawable, android-togglebutton

Hello I had a problem with equate id background from same drawable xml.

I have view with 2 toggle button like this

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/gambar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/g1"
    android:text=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff="" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/g1"
    android:text=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff="" />
```

with the same android:background, how I can get same id source to my code?

I have main activity like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamescene);

    this.tg = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.gambar1);
    this.tg1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    tg.setOnClickListener(this);
    tg1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v == tg){
        Toast.makeText(this, "On " + v.getBackground().getConstantState(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(v == tg1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "On " + v.getBackground().getConstantState(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

and drawable xml like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/bell"/>

<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/hint"/>

<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/blank"/>
```

but, I got different statelist from same background. how I can catch the same resource name entry "g1" to my Activity?

sorry for my bad english

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using this

getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.g1);

Comment: ah thanks I got the idea that I want with `tg.getResources()` and `tg1.getResource` generate the same result. thanks again

Comment: upss sorry I had problem by the code, why with different drawable resources I got the same resource hash? how can I get resource entry name by the toggle button on main activity?